# Trying to sort a list of tuples in python first by date then by greatest number

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of tuples and I am trying to sort by date and then by the greatest number. So basically when you have two dates that are the same it will then put the tuple with the greatest number first. See example below.

**My list of tuples**

```
dataLst = [["Mike", 50, "08/10/2016"], ["Bob", 100, "08/10/2016"], ["Dave", 500, "08/01/2016"], ["Paul", -50, "08/20/2016"], ["Sam", 250, "08/30/2016"]]
```

**I then sort the list by the dates in the tuples.**

```
sDataLst = sorted(dataLst, key=operator.itemgetter(2))
```

**I then sort the sorted list by the numbers in reverse order.**

```
sorted(sDataLst,key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

**When I print the sorted list I get the following.**

```
print sDataLst

[['Dave', 500, '08/01/2016'], ['Mike', 50, '08/10/2016'], ['Bob', 100, '08/10/2016'], ['Paul', -50, '08/20/2016'], ['Sam', 250, '08/30/2016']]
```

If you look at the second and third item in the list which have the same date they should be reversed because the number in the third item is greater then the one in the second item. What I am looking for as a result is the following.

```
[['Dave', 500, '08/01/2016'], ['Bob', 100, '08/10/2016'], ['Mike', 50, '08/10/2016'], ['Paul', -50, '08/20/2016'], ['Sam', 250, '08/30/2016']]
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You know that sorting dates that are in mm/dd/yyyy format won't be in *date order* as such, right?

Comment: Yes i am aware of that but because i choose mm/dd/yyyy it will sort correctly when passed as a string value. but thank you for the note. i will keep that in mind going forward.

Comment: Well no... they won't sort correctly... `12/31/2015` won't come before `01/01/2016` will it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the order of the sorts - the "tie-breakers" are done before the "main" sort which works because Python's sort is stable, so they retain the order of the tiebreaker when sorted into the main order, eg:

```
from datetime import datetime
from operator import itemgetter

dataLst = [["Mike", 50, "08/10/2016"], ["Bob", 100, "08/10/2016"], ["Dave", 500, "08/01/2016"], ["Paul", -50, "08/20/2016"], ["Sam", 250, "08/30/2016"]]
# Sort the tie breaker first
dataLst.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
# Sort on the main key - here we'll use `strptime` to sort as a proper date
dataLst.sort(key=lambda L: datetime.strptime(L[2], '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

This gives:

```
[['Dave', 500, '08/01/2016'],
 ['Bob', 100, '08/10/2016'],
 ['Mike', 50, '08/10/2016'], # Bob and Mike properly ordered...
 ['Paul', -50, '08/20/2016'],
 ['Sam', 250, '08/30/2016']]
```

Comment: Thanks Ninja Puppy.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare the dates as strings because of the order *mm/dd/yyyy*, you could use *datetime* to :

```
from datetime import datetime
strp = datetime.strptime

srted = sorted(dataLst, key=lambda sub: (strp(sub[2],"%m/%d/%Y"), -sub[1]))
```

Or just split and reverse the order of the date to *yyyy, mm, dd:*

```
def iso(sub):
    mm, dd, yy = sub.split("/")
    return yy, mm, dd

srted = sorted(dataLst, key=lambda sub: (iso(sub[2]), -sub[1]))
```

Both give you the same output:

```
 In [24]: sorted(dataLst, key=lambda sub: (iso( sub[2]), -sub[1]))Out[24]: 
[['Dave', 500, '08/01/2016'],
 ['Bob', 100, '08/10/2016'],
 ['Mike', 50, '08/10/2016'],
 ['Paul', -50, '08/20/2016'],
 ['Sam', 250, '08/30/2016']]

In [25]: sorted(dataLst, key=lambda sub: (strp(sub[2],"%m/%d/%Y"), -sub[1]))

Out[25]: 
[['Dave', 500, '08/01/2016'],
 ['Bob', 100, '08/10/2016'],
 ['Mike', 50, '08/10/2016'],
 ['Paul', -50, '08/20/2016'],
 ['Sam', 250, '08/30/2016']]
```

The difference is splitting is way faster as you can see below:

```
In [28]: timeit  sorted(dataLst, key=lambda sub: (strp(sub[2],"%m/%d/%Y"), -sub[1]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 66.4 µs per loop

In [29]: timeit sorted(dataLst, key=lambda sub: (iso( sub[2]), -sub[1]))
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.97 µs per loop
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `-sub[1]` which works nicely here using a tuuple, but not so useful when you have differing types or more complicated ordering... :p (Need Bob before Mike here...)

Comment: @NinjaPuppy, did not realise they wanted to reverse the sort for the ties, I was concentrating on the fact the were comparing the dates completely wrong. Fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Ninja Puppy's answer, but in one sort iteration, not two:

```
dataLst.sort(key=lambda l: (datetime.strptime(l[2], '%m/%d/%Y'), -l[1]))
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't read his answer. I guess it was too long to say the same :)